# Call resx text with parameter

Tags: c#

I have an entry in my resx file like this:
[image]

In my C# Code I try to access this text with parameter with this code:

```
   string.Format(Resource.ProcessedFiles,counter);
```

but I get this error:

```
Input string was not in a correct format
```

How can I pass the parameter to my resx entry?

Comment: In old fasion .... `{0}` (it's becuse new formatting(with names) is compile time only)

Comment: What do you exactly mean?

Comment: put `Processed {0} Files` in the resx